# Magnific Popup gallery with several links to each element

Tags: jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I'm trying to use **Magnific Popup on a Tumblr theme to display the permalink content from each post on a popup via ajax**, instead of its normal behavior which is loading a new page.

I want to provide a pagination system, so you can move to the previous and following permalink content, from the adjacent posts, without leaving the popup. This is easy to get with "Gallery" option on Magnific Popup:

- I create an instance to Magnific Popup targeting the parent container
  to all posts and use the "delegate" option for child items selectors, that will open the popup:

  ```
  $('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
    delegate: '.permalink',
    type:'ajax',
    gallery:{
      enabled:true
    }
  });
  ```
- Each post may have several links with the same `href`, targeting the same permalink
  content, on the "Title", on "Read more" link, on "Date", etc.
- The **problem** is that for each one of these links on the same post, a new instance is
  created on the gallery for the same permalink content. So when you move between items on gallery using navigation arrows, you'll see the same content duplicated for each link targeting the same `href`.

[image: Example]
[image]

This is the intended behavior for Magnific Popup, but **I need a way to avoid that duplication and still have several links pointing to the same content. Is there a way?**

Comment: Is it not just a matter of changing the `delegate` selector to something more specific, like `.post .permalink:first-child`?

Comment: I don't think it's a question of being specific. Each post has several items that need to target its permalink page via popup (title of the post, 'read more' link, date of publication, etc). Whenever you target those items with the `delegate` selector, Magnific Popup will create an instance of this post permalink page on the gallery for each item, repeating the content.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but I had this issue too. I ended up doing this...

HTML:

```
<article id="element-1">
    <a class="popup-link" href="http://example.com">first link</a>
    <a class="popup-link-fake" href="http://example.com">second link</a>
    <a class="popup-link-fake" href="http://example.com">third link</a>
</article>
<article id="element-2">
    <a class="popup-link" href="http://example.com">first link</a>
    <a class="popup-link-fake" href="http://example.com">second link</a>
    <a class="popup-link-fake" href="http://example.com">third link</a>
</article>
<!-- etc... -->
```

jQuery:

```
// call the lightbox on one link element per item
$('.popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type : 'ajax',
    gallery : { enabled : true },
});
// make the other links click that link when clicked
$('.popup-link-fake').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('article').find('.popup-link').click();
});
```